# Set RowNumber by grouping the value if next value is blank

Tags: sql-server

I'm using `Sql Server 2008`. I want to group the Data by a condition and set the RowNumber for it. None of the columns in the table are unique values.

### Grouping Condition

If Any Row occurred as Blank, group the previous not null rows and set Row Number for it.

### Example:

My table Data looks like this:

```
Code    Name    Location

Db1     Name1   N 
Db3     Name3   S
NULL    NULL    NULL
Db1     Name1   N
NULL    NULL    NULL
Db1     Name1   N
NULL    NULL    NULL
Db1     Name1   S
Db4     Name4   S
```

I need the **OUTPUT** like this:

```
Sno     Code    Name    Location

1       Db1     Name1   N
1       Db3     Name3   S
2       Db1     Name1   N
3       Db1     Name1   N
4       Db1     Name1   S
4       Db4     Name4   S
```

Comment: if you don't have any column defining the order of your rows... you are just lucky if you are always getting the same order. That's a bad table design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as the next row without having a column to ORDER BY. So I added an id as identity to solve this:

```
DECLARE @t table(id int identity(1,1), Code char(3),  Name char(5), Location char(1))

INSERT @t values
('Db1','Name1','N'),('Db3','Name3','S'),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
('Db1','Name1','N'),(NULL,NULL,NULL),('Db1','Name1','N'),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),('Db1','Name1','S'),('Db4','Name4','S')

;WITH cte as
(
  SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by id)
    - row_number() over (order by id * case when code is not null then 1 end) x, 
    Code, Name, Location
FROM @t
)
SELECT 
  dense_rank() over (order by x) Sno,
  Code, Name, Location
FROM cte 
WHERE code is not null
```

Result:

```
Sno Code  Name   Location
1   Db1   Name1  N
1   Db3   Name3  S
2   Db1   Name1  N
3   Db1   Name1  N
4   Db1   Name1  S
4   Db4   Name4  S
```